# Finding the number of divisors of $N=2^7\times3^5\times5^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, divisor-counting-function

Find the number of divisors of $N=2^7\times3^5\times5^3$ which are of the form $4t+1$, where $t$ is a natural number.

I understood the fact, that $5$ can be written in the form of $4t+1$. Also, every even power of $3$ can be written in the form of $4t+1.$

for example:-
$4(2)+1=9$ which is an even power of $3$
$4(0)+1=1$ which is an even power of $3$: $3^0$
$4(20)+1=81$ which is also an even power of $3$

Why are we multiplying power of $5$ that is $4$ powers of $5$ ($5^0$, $5^1$, $5^2$, $5^3$) and three powers of 3($3^0$, $3^2$, $3^4$)

That is $4\times3=12$.
And then why are we subtracting $-1$ from $12$. ( Final answer is $11$)

Why not adding $4+3=7$

Comment: overlap of the powers maybe ...  $5^0=3^0$ ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee - that wouldn't do it. They're probably looking for proper factors, i.e excluding $1$

Comment: It's because they want $t$ in $4t+1$ to be a natural number, and they're not counting $0\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: they ask for divisors ...

Comment: Well, $1$ is a divisor, and a proper divisor. The only reason to exclude it would be the "$t$ is a natural number" condition.

Comment: to be fair my comment does show why they aren't added like the OP  thought 4+3=7.

Comment: The answer IS $12\quad$ namely
$\{1,5,9,25,45,81,125,225,405,1125,2025,10125\}$. Why do they say $11$?

Answer (score 4):

We multiply instead of adding because we're counting the number of ways to mix and match elements from a set of $4$ with elements from a set of $3$. Watch:

$5^03^0, 5^03^2,5^03^4$

That's $3$.

$5^13^0, 5^13^2,5^13^4$

That's another $3$.

$5^23^0, 5^23^2,5^23^4$

Another $3$.

$5^33^0, 5^33^2,5^33^4$

Another $3$.

That's $3$, a total of $4$ times. Thus, $4$ times $3$.

Finally, we subtract $1$ because one of these answers, $5^03^0$ equals $1$, which is $4t+1$ with $t=0$. We don't count $0$ as a natural number, so we have to exclude that one.

Comment: Thanks, the final part had me stumped, I forgot some people use a different convention. But do we know for certain that this is the convention used in gmat?

Comment: A little bit of Googling leads me to believe that it is, but I find no authoritative source. Otherwise, I can't see why the official answer would be $11$, though.

Comment: I still did not understand why are we subtracting -1 @GTonyJacobs

Comment: And why do we need to mix the elements when we know that $5^1$ will divide N. Why do we need to mix and match it with $3^0$?

Comment: Combining $5^1$ with $3^0$ is the same as just taking $5^1$ by itself, but writing it as $5^13^0$ is a good way to list everything systematically. Either way, the divisor in question is $5$.